# Error in Python script "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, predict

I'm following [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/linear-svc-example-scikit-learn-svm-python) to make this ML prediction:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm

x = [1, 5, 1.5, 8, 1, 9]
y = [2, 8, 1.8, 8, 0.6, 11]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()

X = np.array([[1,2],
             [5,8],
             [1.5,1.8],
             [8,8],
             [1,0.6],
             [9,11]])

y = [0,1,0,1,0,1]
X.reshape(1, -1)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)
clf.fit(X,y)

print(clf.predict([0.58,0.76]))
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and I get error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:"
I think the script is for older versions, but I don't know how to convert it to the 3.6 version.

Already try with the:

```
X.reshape(1, -1)
```

Comment: Which line is producing the error?

Comment: `X = X.reshape(1, -1)`. Reshape is not in-place.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: I'd guess the last line `clf.predict(<a-1d-thing>)`, since `X` is already two-dimensional (useless `reshape` notwithstanding).

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, the last line is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist whats the right place for the reshape?

Comment: @JonTargaryen: What version of scikit-learn are you using? This isn't supposed to become an error until version 0.19, which isn't released yet.

Comment: @JonTargaryen the reshape is in the right place, but you are discarding the result. Assign the result back to `X`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist , thanks that helps mine too

Comment: making long answer short: ```regr.fit(np.array(x_train).reshape(-1,1), np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1))``` where x_train = pd.read_sql_query('select * from YourTable', cnx).NeededColumn

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You are just supposed to provide the `predict` method with the same 2D array, but with one value that you want to process (or more). In short, you can just replace

```
[0.58,0.76]
```

With

```
[[0.58,0.76]]
```

And it should work.

EDIT: This answer became popular so I thought I'd add a little more explanation about ML. The short version: we can only use `predict` on data that is of the same dimensionality as the training data (`X`) was.

In the example in question, we give the computer a bunch of rows in `X` (with 2 values each) and we show it the correct responses in `y`. When we want to `predict` using new values, our program expects the same - a **bunch** of rows. Even if we want to do it to just one row (with two values), that row has to be part of another array.

Comment: but why does that work? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: how do you achieve this for larger dataframes? (dynamically)

Comment: Why does it have to be a 2D array? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Thanks, that was always an error I got, simple solution.

Answer (score 23):

The problem is occurring when you run prediction on the array `[0.58,0.76]`. Fix the problem by reshaping it before you call `predict()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm

x = [1, 5, 1.5, 8, 1, 9]
y = [2, 8, 1.8, 8, 0.6, 11]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()

X = np.array([[1,2],
             [5,8],
             [1.5,1.8],
             [8,8],
             [1,0.6],
             [9,11]])

y = [0,1,0,1,0,1]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)
clf.fit(X,y)

test = np.array([0.58, 0.76])
print test       # Produces: [ 0.58  0.76]
print test.shape # Produces: (2,) meaning 2 rows, 1 col

test = test.reshape(1, -1)
print test       # Produces: [[ 0.58  0.76]]
print test.shape # Produces (1, 2) meaning 1 row, 2 cols

print(clf.predict(test)) # Produces [0], as expected
```

Comment: Since pandas 0.19.0 you need to add `.values` before `.reshape(1, -1)` as in :

`test = test.values.reshape(1, -1)`

Comment: my prediction error is with LightGDM model and I know how to reshape but the LightGBM creates its own lbg.Dataset and not sure how to setup reshape or get the prediction working for LightGDM, my posted question is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894373/lightgbm-prediction-issue-valueerror-input-numpy-ndarray-or-list-must-be-2-dime

Answer (score 12):

I use the below approach.

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['year']],df.income)

reg.predict([[2136]])
```

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue except that the data type of the instance I wanted to predict was a `panda.Series` object.

Well I just needed to predict one input instance. I took it from a slice of my data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(BiogasPlant.objects.all()))
test = df.iloc[-1:]       # sliced it here
```

In this case, you'll need to convert it into a 1-D array  and then `reshape` it.

```
 test2d = test.values.reshape(1,-1)
```

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.values.html), `values` will convert Series into a numpy array.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. You just have to make it an array and moreover you have to put double squared brackets to make it a single element of the 2D array as first bracket initializes the array and the second makes it an element of that array.

So simply replace the last statement by:

```
print(clf.predict(np.array[[0.58,0.76]]))
```

Comment: You're creating an array here so you want np.array[[0.58,0.76])  *not square brackets

Answer (score 3):

Just insert the argument between a double square bracket:

```
regressor.predict([[values]])
```

that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue earlier but I have somehow found the solution,
You can try `reg.predict([[3300]])`.

The API used to allow scalar value but now you need to give a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

With one feature my Dataframe list converts to a Series. I had to convert it back to a Dataframe list and it worked.

```
if type(X) is Series:
    X = X.to_frame()
```

Comment: So were you able to use a pyspark dataframe with sklearn? If so, could I see a code snippet for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Just enclose your numpy object with two square brackets or vice versa.**

For example:

If initially your `x = [8,9,12,7,5]`

change it to `x = [ [8,9,12,7,5] ]`.

That should fix the dimension issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

np.array(x)[:, None]

Answer (score -1):

The X and Y matrix of Independent Variable and Dependent Variable respectively to DataFrame from int64 Type so that it gets converted from 1D array to 2D array.. 
i.e X=pd.DataFrame(X) and Y=pd.dataFrame(Y) where pd is of pandas class in python. and thus feature scaling in-turn doesn't lead to any error!