# ValueError on sklearn's linear_model.predict

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, valueerror

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
df = pd.read_csv("homeprices.csv")
df
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(df[['area']], df.price)
model.predict(5000)
```

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
>   array=5000.
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in python script "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554008/error-in-python-script-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead)

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
model.predict(5000)
```

to:

```
model.predict([[5000]])
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation as to why this works, yet the OP's code did not.