# How to know a model expects the input in a format like 2D array must be 1D array?

Tags: arrays, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

Considering [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554008/error-in-python-script-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead), I can not yet get the reason ***how to know the model expects*** the input
must be in a format.

According to the error message, you have input data in the format [45000, 50000, 60000, ...]. But the model expects the input in the format like [[45000], [50000], [60000], ...] - a list of the lists. So reshape(-1, 1) just changes a format.

Why y not to be as 2Darray? Why just X must be?

Comment: In general, a scikit-learn model will expect `X` to be of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` or, if you only have one feature, `(n_samples,)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of `sklearn.svm.SVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict), for the `predict` method:

> **Parameters**
>
> **X: *{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features) or (n_samples_test, n_samples_train)***
>
> For kernel=”precomputed”, the expected shape of X is (n_samples_test, n_samples_train).

So, even when you have exactly one value `X` for which you want the prediction, your input shape needs to be `(1, n_features)`, since you have `nsamples` equal to `1`, instead of `(n_features)`, which is not supported.