# Python - Linear Regression Model by Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I would like support trying to get a linear regression model built by 'ClientID' grouping.

I have managed to pull together the below functions but I am getting errors, that said I am very new to Python so would be open to any other ideas you may have.

The data below is from my dataframe dfTotal3 and the two variables I am using Steps (count of steps the client did in a day) and WeightDiff (change in weight since last input).

```py
def model(dfTotal3, target):
    y = dfTotal3[['Steps']].values
    X = dfTotal3[['WeightDiff']].values
    return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, y).predict(target))

def group_predictions(df, target):
    target = dfWeightComp['DTWDG']
    return dfTotal3.groupby('ClientID').apply(model, target)

group_predictions(dfTotal3, dfTotal3['DTWDG'])
```

Error Output:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-0.03231707 -0.03780488 -0.04512195 -0.04615385].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: `X = X.reshape(1, -1)` is probably what you want before calling fit.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I've thrown this in:
def model(dfTotal3, target):
    y = dfTotal3[['Steps']].values
    X = dfTotal3[['WeightDiff']].values
    X = X.reshape(1, -1)
    return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, y).predict(target)) 

returned the following error:
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error comes from:

```
return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, y).predict(target))
```

Specifically I speculate there is an issue with this part of the code `.predict(target)`

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554008/error-in-python-script-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead) is suggesting to change your target i.e.:

`target = dfWeightComp['DTWDG']`

to:

`target = dfWeightComp[['DTWDG']]`

Comment: Thanks Simon, I do get a warning is this something I should be worried about?

UserWarning: X has feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted without feature names
  warnings.warn(

Comment: It means that when you defined your independent variable for training the model (`X = dfTotal3[['WeightDiff']].values`) you only used values from the DataFrame, where in your `target` variable you used the whole column. For consistency purposes you can change your target to `target = dfWeightComp[['DTWDG']].values` or vice versa and remove the `.values` from your `X` and `y`

Comment: Really helpful Simon, thanks (apologies if it was a stupid question!)

Comment: Hi,

The output looks like the following:

ClientID
AB00001    [22378.285131195335, 21297.06927617608, 21315....
AB00002    [20483.8305898491, 18159.833358735963, 18199.3...
AB00003    [22623.58584474885, 19964.634731382826, 20009....
AB00005    [15635.423214285713, 14758.849920443217, 14773...

I was expecting one number by ClientID, I am also struggling to access the lists as it has no column name? - Any help would be greatly appreciated